# '-print_statistics' linker option produces error in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, llvm, ld

I want to profile linking phase of our big C++ project because it takes up to 30 minutes when linking iOS project using Xcode or `xcodebuild`.

`$ man ld` tells it's possible to use '-print_statistics' command line option. But setting this option through "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings produces an error during `Ld`:

`clang: error: unknown argument: '-print_statistics'`

Looks like Xcode build system some how checks "Other Linker Flags" and does not recognize the '-print_statistics'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shaiba guessed Xcode uses Clang/LLVM. Behind the scene LLVM uses  [LLD](http://lld.llvm.org/) linker which points that

```
"LLD is a drop-in replacement for the GNU linkers. That accepts the same command line arguments and linker scripts as GNU"
```

as one of the main features.

Your mistake that you try to pass linker argument directly. Its should be passed through `clang`

```
-Wl,<arg>,<arg2>...
Pass the comma separated arguments in <arg> to the linker

-X
-Xlinker <arg>, --for-linker <arg>, --for-linker=<arg>
Pass <arg> to the linker
```

Try to set `-Wl,-print_statistics`

Comment: You are right! It is possible to pass `-Wl,-print_statistics` using "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

XCode uses Clang/LLVM, so my guess is it will also use [lld](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/lld-5.0/ld.lld-5.0.1.en.html) as the linker, not `ld`, which is the GNU linker. `lld` does not have `-print-statistics`, hence the error.